# Temperature logging of li-ion cells

Tags: applied-mechanics

I'm looking to measure and log the surface temperature of lithium ion cells (cylindrical and pouch). I tried using LM35 sensors with an Arduino, but, the drift was too much somehow. Any suggestions on how this system can be improved, as in - use different sensors or change the microcontroller?

Comment: Can you provide us some more details on how you mounted the sensor? Pictures would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Analog can by tricky, because your signal can be distorted and the system will still work.. sort of.

I would recommend switching to a digital sensor, that way you can avoid all the analog uncertainty. The DS18B20 is popular and quite accurate.